# Extend sw-context-menu-item and use custom config page

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

How can I extend `sw-context-menu-item` and use a custom config action route?
If i override `sw-context-menu-item` and there is another plugin that does that , it wont work.
Also tried to extend it with this but with no luck:

```
Component.extend('my-custom-extension', 'sw-context-menu-item', {
    `<template>
    <sw-context-menu-item
        :icon="icon"
        :label="label"
        :disabled="disabled"
        :routerLink="routerLink"
        @click="onClick"
        class="sw-context-menu-item"
    />
   </template>`
});
```

Is there another way to change the plugin config to point to another route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding the original component, you could alter the `routerLink` object on creation.

```js
Component.override('sw-context-menu-item', {
    created() {
        if (!this.routerLink || this.routerLink.name !== 'route.to.replace') {
            return;
        }

        this.routerLink.name = 'new.route';
        this.routerLink.params = {};
    },
});
```